# node reference ordering

Tags: 7, theming, hooks

I have a content type "Review" and there there is dropdown for brands, I want to order dropdown list by alphabetical order. is there any way to reordering drupal node reference dropdown?

Answer (score 0):

If you chose auto-complete for your node reference field & if number of item to be added is set to unlimited then you get to re-order the values which appear.

Though my answer is not proper for question which you have asked as you are asking for select field but this way I have done it..

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways you can do this

1. By altering the menu path used for autocomplete and change the results based on your custom approach. Refer to this article [here](https://x-team.com/blog/extending-drupal-7-autocomplete-fields-output/)
2. Create a new view with "Entity reference" as display and in the filter choose content type, Sort results alphabetically or based on your custom needs. Add an entity reference field and then under "Entity selection" switch mode to "Views: Filter by an entity reference view" and select the view you have created.
   [image]

In either way, you can get the results Alphabetically based on your needs.